# Can Send/Receive iOS push notification in GSM network?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, gsm

My current iOS app want to send and receive data in GSM network because device only have GSM nor wi-fi, nor 3G, nor LTE...etc.

so I try to send and receive data via SMS. I can send data via SMS app(we can't use it background also) but can't listen incoming message in 3rd party app in iOS.

so I come up with the apple push notifications. my problems are

1. can send/receive push notification in GSM network ?
2. Is there any way to send/receive data using GSM network ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be a conditional "yes"  Assuming the user has an active data plan, data can be sent and received through a GSM connection.  APN can be received any time there's a data connection, so it works fine through a GSM connection.

If you're asking if there's any way to send/receive data if the user has no data plan in place, then the answer is no.